# I18n breaks unit tests with Angular and Angular/localize

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, internationalization, nrwl-nx

I had a lot of unit tests that were running well. After installing `@angular/localize` and adding `i18n` attributes to html tags, all tests started failing with the following error:

```
    It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n.
    Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
    Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
    (For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.
    For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)
```

Even after following the instructions, the tests still fail. Here's what I tried:

- Running `npm install @angular/localize` and `npx nx g @angular/localize:ng-add --project=<project name>` (This project uses [NX](https://nx.dev/))
- Adding `import '@angular/localize/init';` to `polyfills.ts`
- Adding `import '../../../node_modules/@angular/localize/init';` to `polyfills.ts`
- Adding both imports mentioned above to `main.ts`
- Adding `/// <reference types="@angular/localize" />` to `main.ts`
- Adding:

```
import { TextEncoder } from 'util';
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
```

to `polyfills.ts`, `main.ts`, and the `.spec` file.

None of these fixed the issue.

Some info on what I have installed:

```
Angular: 16.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.5
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.5
@angular/cdk                    16.2.7
@angular/cli                    16.2.5
@angular/fire                   7.6.1
@angular/material               16.2.7
@schematics/angular             16.2.5
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6
zone.js                         0.13.3
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is the testing library ?

Comment: @AymericFi It's jest

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Take a look at [this answer on nx's repo](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4751#issuecomment-1396557273)

The real solution is to add the lines I mentioned below to `test-setup.ts`:

> To be able to run unit tests I added these two steps in test-setup.ts:
>
> ```
> import '@angular/localize/init'; 
> ... import { TextEncoder } from
> 'util'; global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
> ```

---

---

I ended up solving my own issue. The solution was adding the following lines to each `.spec` file:

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
...
import { TextEncoder } from 'util';
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
```

Would be nice if someone could figure out a way to configure this globally though.